# sequence and series for telescoping terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions

$x=\frac{1}{16 \sqrt{17}+17 \sqrt{16}}+\frac{1}{17 \sqrt{18}+18 \sqrt{17}}+\ldots \ldots+\frac{1}{144 \sqrt{145}+145 \sqrt{144}}$ the value of $\mathrm{X}$ is approximately.

(A) 0.09
(B) 0.17
(C) 0.29
(D) 0.41

Please help me in the above.
I tried but got to sqrt(a)-sqrt(b)/ab  where a is the bigger of each term in the fraction
but how to get the series to have a common denominator to cancel the terms.

Comment: Take $\sqrt{ab}$ common from denominator, rest telescopes in fractions.

Comment: thankyou, but please some more hints

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint (re telescoping terms):

Try multiplying the first term by
$$\frac{17\sqrt{16} - 16\sqrt{17}}{17\sqrt{16} - 16\sqrt{17}}$$ and see what happens.